# writeOGR error: length(dsn) == 1L is not TRUE

Tags: shapefile, r, for-loop

I'm running a for loop R that results in a shapefile being written with each iteration. The for loop runs successfully once, with a shapefile being written out, but then on the second iteration I get this error:

```
Error in writeOGR(temp, outfile, layer = complete_paste, driver = "ESRI Shapefile",  : 
  length(dsn) == 1L is not TRUE
```

For some reason, I cannot find any other question encountering this error with writeOGR(). I don't know what it means. Can anyone explain?

If it helps, here's the entire code I'm running. Basically I'm taking a large shapefile, and exporting smaller shapefiles from it by values in shp1$Vector.

```
library(rgdal)


shp1<- readOGR("/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/Zone_Fixup/Z1/z1_scrub/z1_merge.shp")

output_path1<- "/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/Zone_Fixup/Z1/z1_split/"

#Begin for loop to split shapefile by shp1$Vector values
for(i in 1:length(shp1$Vector)){

  #subset by join_id (Vector)
  temp<- shp1[shp1$Vector==shp1$Vector[i],]
  id_paste<- paste(temp$Vector)

  #Create strings for shapefile write-out
  outfile<- paste(output_path1, "Zone1_", id_paste, ".shp", sep = "")
  complete_paste<- paste("Zone1_", id_paste, sep = "")

  #Write out shapefile
  writeOGR(temp, outfile, layer = complete_paste, driver = "ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = TRUE)

}
```

Comment: Are you expecting `id_paste` to return something like `'apples'`? Because I'm pretty sure it must be returning `c('apples', 'apples', 'apples')` at least some of the time.

Comment: yes but id_paste is just to inform what the file name will be in the output. No two will values will be the same so they won't overwrite each other. What does the error message mean? I don't know what's preventing the shapefile from being written out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've confirmed in the comments, `id_paste` is a vector any time `temp` has more than one row. This means you'd be sending multiple copies of `outfile` and `complete_paste` to `writeOGR()`.

run `paste('How do you like them ', c('apples', 'apples', 'apples'), '?', sep = '')` to see what happens when you supply a vector to `paste()`.

Try `id_paste = shp1$Vector[i]` instead.