# Reading shapefiles using for loop: Error in readOGR() : length(dsn) == 1L is not TRUE

Tags: shapefile, r, for-loop

I'm using a for loop to read in multiple shapefiles within a directory and manipulate them individually. Presently I cannot do this because the for loop results in the error: "Error in readOGR(shp_paste) : length(dsn) == 1L is not TRUE". Not a single shapefile is read in; this error occurs immediately. I do not know what this means, and can only find a similar post with this error for writeOGR ([link here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306194/writeogr-error-lengthdsn-1l-is-not-true)). When I try to load the shapefiles individually into R Studio, I'm successful in doing so (though I haven't tried individually for all of them, there are too many). What could be causing this error? It's difficult to go through the files in the directory individually to identify potential problems because there are over 10,000.
Below is my code:

```
    library(rgdal)
    input_path<- "/Volumes/Directory/data_folder/"
    files<- list.files(input_path, pattern = "[.]shp$")

    for(f in files){
    ifile<- list.files(input_path, f)
    shp_paste<- paste(input_path, ifile, sep = "")
    shp1<- readOGR(shape_paste)
    print("success!")
    }
```

Running this code produces the error above.

Comment: In my test of your code, it is pasting the filename to the end of the path without a separator, making a nonexistent filename. You could instead use [file.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110076/function-to-concatenate-paths).  I also highly recommend adding print statements in your function as a test so that you can see what output is being produced at each state.

Comment: Could you paste what you're getting? What I get from shp_paste is "/Volumes/Directory/data_folder/file1.shp", for example. If you took this and put it directly into readOGR it would read the shapefile successfully. I think the problem is someplace else

Comment: Your code assigns to `shp_paste` and then reads from `shape_paste`. Please check your examples fail correctly before posting them - by which I mean it *doesn't* produce the error you say it does!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are passing a list to the read function instead of a single file

When you call

`shp_paste<- paste(input_path, ifile, sep = "")`

the `ifile` object can be a list of files, so shp_paste has a length greater than 1.

You might change this by changing the code to

`shp_paste<- paste(input_path, f, sep = "")`

since you are iterating over files.  Or you could just list the full path in the first place:

`files<- list.files(input_path, pattern = "[.]shp$", full.names=T)`

So this code should work:

```
    library(rgdal)
    input_path <- "/Volumes/Directory/data_folder/"
    files <- list.files(input_path, pattern = "[.]shp$", full.names=T)

    for (f in files){
    shp1 <- readOGR(f)
    print("success!")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `full.names=TRUE` to get the full path to the shapefiles, and then use `lapply` to loop over the shapefiles and read them all into a list:

```
> files<- list.files(input_path, pattern = "[.]shp$",full.names=TRUE)
> allShapes = lapply(files, readOGR)

> plot(allShapes[[1]]) # to plot the first one.
```

or loop over them:

```
> for(shp in files){
    sp = readOGR(shp)
    message("REad ",nrow(sp))
  }
```